# Obtener un valor utilizando "command" en un boton para una calculadora

Tags: python

estoy iniciando en python y a la vez que hago un curso estoy diseñando una calculadora básica.
Lo que me pasa, a diferencia del profesor del curso, es que cuando corro el programa y me sale la calculadora, al presionar por ejemplo el 4, no se me imprime el 4 en la calculadora. Quizás tengo mal el código. Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()

miFrame=Frame(raiz)

miFrame.pack()

#---------pantalla--------

numeroPantalla=StringVar()

pantalla=Entry(miFrame)
pantalla.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(bg="white", fg="#03f943",justify="right")

#---------pulsaciones-teclado---------

def numeroPulsado():
    
    numeroPantalla.set("4")

#-----fila1------

boton4=Button(miFrame,text="4",width=3,command=numeroPulsado)
boton4.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

En la parte de command=numeroPulsado, tambien lo probe como numeroPulsado() pero tampoco realizaba lo que queria. Cabe aclarar que no me dio error.

Comment: Creaste el StringVar, pero no lo estás asociando a ningún widget. Por eso no te funciona. Tenés que agregar en el entry "textvariable=[la variable donde está el stringvar]"

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rta. Donde deberia agregar eso? Lo agregue debajo de ```numeroPantalla=StringVar()```
Pero no me funciona todavia.
Perdon la pregunta, estoy empezando con el lenguaje y hay cosas de la sintaxis que a lo mejor no las entiendo del todo.

Comment: De nada! Tendrías que agregarlo en la parte donde creas el entry, quedandote así: "pantalla=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=numeroPantalla)"

Comment: Que grande, muchisimas gracias! Me re sirvio y pude.

Comment: De nada, me alegra haberte ayudado c: